# Create MSI file from c# outlook addin in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have c# outlook addin created in visual studio 2013.

It has windows forms also.

I am getting mad on generating msi file, any easier solution/steps for me, please ?

Mainly tell me, after completing the process, where do I find the final MSI file (like bin/release folder) ?

I installed this - https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

as well as installshield limited edition installer.

I was able to build it and ran the installation file(.exe) from disks folder and it is installing but not showing anything in the outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Deploying an Office Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx) section in MSDN. It describes two possible options for deploying your Office solution in depth:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx)

It is up to you which way is to choose.

> I was able to build it and ran the installation file(.exe) from disks folder and it is installing but not showing anything in the outlook.

There are multiple reasons why you don't see your add-in in Office applications.

First of all, make sure that you did all the steps described in the previously mentioned articles. Then I'd suggest checking the required windows registry keys for COM add-ins, see [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) for more information.

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

You can read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article in MSDN.

Finally, you may also check out the Trust Center settings in Outlook. The Macro Security settings can be applied to add-ins as well. May be it is required to sign the add-in with a digial signature and etc.

Comment: I successfully created setup.exe and its working. How to make .msi file from it ? bcz my requirement is to build msi file . Thanks.

Comment: Typically Windows Installer uses two files: an msi as a database for your files and custom actions and the unmanaged setup.exe file for checking prerequsites on the machine. Check out the InstallShield setting on the machine. Also you may consider using WiX instead of InstallShield.

Comment: Fyi - Somewhere in the project directory I found msi file, I hope that works fully(installation, addin features working). I tried compiling cd-rom(not singleimage), and not sure if that generated that msi file.